# How to measure wavelength of gamma-rays

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

How can we experimentally measure the wavelength of gamma-rays, say for about 0.7MeV without knowing the exact energy and without measuring energy, i.e. sort of direct measurement.

Comment: The energy of a photon is given as E=hc/lambda (h..Plancks const., c..speed of light, lambda..wavelength), so you can directly calculate the wavelength given the energy. This is approx. 1.7712e-12 m for 0.7 MeV.

Answer (score 5):

The direct method is by crystal diffraction.

Here is an article by Kessler *et al* (1988):

[High accuracy, absolute wavelength determination of capture gamma-ray energies for E≤5 MeV and the direct determination of binding energies in light nuclei](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4616/14/S/017/meta)

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment, for clarity of terms used:

> without knowing the exact energy and without measuring energy,

The term "gamma rays"  used as  a term describing a classical electromagnetic wave of specific frequency and wavelength is fine.

The term "gamma" is attributed to a photon, a quantum mechanical particle of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), which is **a point particle**, thus **has no wavelength** , and has mass zero. Its energy is given by $hν$ where h is the Planck  constant and $ν$ is the **frequency of the corresponding classical electromagnetic** wave when one has a large number of photons. When the energy of a gamma photon is known, then the wavelength of the classical wave it will contribute to if many gammas of that frequency are accumulated ( [see this to see how single photons](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) even one at time build a classical interference pattern) can be calculated.

> i.e. sort of direct measurement.

Knowing the energy of a single gamma photon **is a direct measurement**,  and the [continuity of mathematics](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) between classical electrodynamics, and quantum electrodynamics ensures that is so, so it is a direct measurement of the wavelength too

Of course the experiment linked by Peter is also a direct measurement, from the classical side.